# wkhtmltopdf issues rendering bootstrap and angular page

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, wkhtmltopdf

Currently I am trying to convert an angular and bootstrap heavy url using wkhtmltopdf. However, the result of the conversion is simply just a blank pdf with a small rectangle that matches the color of the webpages background. I have a sample output from jsbin I'm using to test angular and bootstrap, and the pdf comes out as intended (http://output.jsbin.com/qucaravupi), only real difference is my sites html requires login and authentication (which I'm using --cookie option to pass in).

Trying to pdf the bootstrap homepage results in sslHandshakeError, so I'm unable to determine if the issue is server side or a result of the page failing to render via wkhtmltopdf. I can use curl to grab the page info from https://getbootstrap.com/css/, but can't use wkhtmltopdf to convert it so I know it's not a redirect problem. Any ideas as to what can be the issue?

Comment: For anyone that finds this, it looks like QTWeb was fighting with our newer version of JQuery. We switched over to Phantomjs and all is good.